# pandas: mean of previous 10 rows with fixed window

Tags: python, pandas

Just I created sampled dataframe. Need to measure the mean of previous 10 values and get that value in another column other rows shows nan.

```
np.random.seed(42)
sp= sorted(np.random.randint(0,200,55))
odo = sorted(np.random.randint(0,40,55))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sp':sp,'odo':odo})

# Getting rolling mean of 10 values
df2 =df1.rolling(10).agg('mean')

# It is giving result continuous

# I want below to result able with indexing.
df3 = df2[9::10]
```

Expected result like this

```
       sp   odo
9    17.7   2.9
19   56.2   8.2
29   89.1  15.4
39  120.7  23.4
49  167.9  30.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `rolling.mean` but a `groupby.mean` by chunks of 10 rows:

```
df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1))//10).mean()
```

To have the same indices as you showed:

```
n = 10
df1.groupby((np.arange(len(df1))//n+1)*n-1).mean()
```

Output:

```
       sp   odo
9    17.7   2.9
19   56.2   8.2
29   89.1  15.4
39  120.7  23.4
49  167.9  30.7
59  189.2  37.2
```

For only groups with 10 values:

```
n = 10
l = len(df1)//n*n
df1.iloc[:l].groupby((np.arange(l)//n+1)*n-1).mean()
```

Output:

```
       sp   odo
9    17.7   2.9
19   56.2   8.2
29   89.1  15.4
39  120.7  23.4
49  167.9  30.7
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. If i want to add these values in another column where each 10th rows shows this value and others shows NaN values. Is there is way? If I try directly with ```df1['mean'] = df1.groupby((np.arange(len(df1))//18)). mean () ``` it is showing ValueError..

Comment: The `groupby.mean` outputs 2 columns, you can't assign to a single column. Try: `df1[['mean_sp', 'mean_odo']] = df1.groupby((np.arange(len(df1))//n+1)*n-1).mean()`

Comment: If ```df1.groupby((np.arange(len(df1))//18))['sp'].mean()``` for this can we add another column?

Comment: ```n = 11,
df1['mean']= df1.groupby((np.arange(len(df1))//n+1)*n-1)['sp'].mean()``` 
it is showing result. You cleared this in ans. Now you can understand what I want to do.

Comment: This is working fine for me, adds the mean every `n` rows

Comment: Yes it is working for me also.. thank you for great help.. I posted it to show you what I want.